# %2 in batch file is ignored on execution in command prompt

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, prompt

I have an image file named `first%20second.png`

I have a `test.bat` file that renames images.

It looks like this:

```
Timeout 3
Copy "C:\first%20second.png" "C:\sub\first%20second.png"
Timeout 3
```

When the batch file runs it does this instead

`Copy "C:\first0second.png" "C:\sub\first0second.png"`

The `%2` does not get included

why is this?

Demonstration of the occurrence

[image]

Comment: I found a similar post answering my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907057/ignore-percent-sign-in-batch-file

Comment: You have to double the percent sign such as: `Copy "C:\first%%20second.png" "C:\sub\first%%20second.png"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to double the percent sign to escape it properly in a batch script.

**Command**

```
Copy "C:\first%%20second.png" "C:\sub\first%%20second.png"
```

---

### Further Resources

- [Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

  > **Escaping Percents**
  >
  > The `%` character has a special meaning for [command line parameters](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) and FOR 
  >   parameters.
  >
  > To treat a percent as a regular character, double it:
  >
  > `%%`